# Where is not a member of System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String) Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

Application type is Windows Forms Application but I'm using it as a helper project in a solution so it doesn't actually have any forms in the project.

Option Infer is on. Using .net 3.5

I tried referencing System.Core, System.Data, System.Data.Linq but none worked.

```
Dim lis As New List(Of String)
lis.Add("orange")
lis.Where(Function(x) x = "apple").ToList()
```

Getting compile error:

> 'Where' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)'

I've been searching for a while now. It works fine in the parent project but not in the helper project. What do I need to do to get 'Where' working on my list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need both

- a reference to `System.Core` (which you already have) and
- `Imports System.Linq` at the top of your code file (which you are probably missing). Alternatively, you can globally import the namespace for your whole project (see below for details).

---

**How do I know that?**

The extension method you are trying to use is `Enumerable.Where`. [Its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-3.5) says the following:

> Namespace:
> System.Linq
> Assembly:
> System.Core.dll

The first line is the namespace you need to import, the second one the DLL you need to reference.

**Why do I need to import the namespace?**

Because you want to use it as an extension method. If you use it as a regular method (`Enumerable.Where(lis, ...)`), you can just use the fully qualified class name instead of importing the namespace (i.e., `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(lis, ...)`). However, if you use it as an extension method (`lis.Where(...)`), you need to have the namespace imported.

**Why don't I need that in my other project?**

Visual Basic allows you [to specify globally "imported namespaces"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-imported-namespaces-visual-basic?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN) in the "References" tab of the project properties. It's possible that the namespace is imported project-wide in one of your projects but not the other one.

Comment: Lovely! works beautifully.